# Use excel auto filter search function in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a column with numbers.
I want to autofilter only number which contains 00.

I used search function of autofilter it worked. In picture its working:
[image]
But I do not know how to use this search function in vba.

I used "contains criteria" in excel autofilter as well as in vba but it does not give result for numbers. It works for text only.

I want a vba code to filter only numbers that contains 00.

Thanks for help

Comment: Is the question about using VBA to create an autofilter rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, although "Contains" is provided as an option in the Custom Autofilter dialog, it is ineffective on numbers. A fairly simple way of achieving what you want is to use a helper column, which converts your numbers to text and then search the text column using the same Custom Autofilter.

If you use

`=TEXT(number,"#")`

to convert each cell containing a `number` to text, then you will be able to find numbers which have 00 to the left of the decimal separator (. in UK/US or , in much of Europe). If you want to include 00 to the right of the decimal separator (or even straddling it), then adjust the second argument to (for example)

`=TEXT(number,"#.####")`

where the number of #'s to the right of the decimal separator is equal to the maximum number of decimal places contained in your column of numbers. Note that this representation will suppress trailing zeroes - so 1.1200 in the number column will show as 1.12 in the text column (and so will not appear in the filtered list).

### EDIT - DOING IT WITH VBA

The `Range.AutoFilter` method, does not, unfortunately, provide functionality equivalent to "Search" in the drop-down dialog that appears when the data filter button is selected on a worksheet.

The documentation for the method ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter ) shows that you can construct your own custom filter - see the third example listed in the documentation.

Therefore, one way forward would be to construct your own filter. There are a couple of things to note in doing this. First, the elements in the filtering array must all be text strings (even though the values you want to filter are all numbers). Second, the filter can be supplied as a variable rather than using the construct `Criteria1:=Array( ... )` shown in the example.

With a worksheet containing the integers 1 to 1,000,000 in range A2:A1000001, the code below created an autofilter which filtered out the 33219 rows containing double-zeroes. It took about 8 seconds on a modest laptop - a Lenovo Ideapad 3. Whether you get similar performance and whether the performance you achieve is compatible with your requirements, only you can determine.

```
Sub Main()

Dim strItems() As String, strValue As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, intValue As Integer

j = -1

For i = 1 To 1000000

    intValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    strValue = CStr(intValue) 'Convert number to string
    
    'If number contains 00 but not 000 (or more),
    'add to filter array (strItems)
    If InStr(strValue, "00") > 0 Then
        
        If InStr(strValue, "000") = 0 Then
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve strItems(j)
            strItems(j) = strValue
        End If
    
    End If

Next i

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$1000001").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=strItems, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

As you can observe, all the code except the last substantive line is devoted to reading and processing the range A2:A1000001 and building the array of filter values as variable `strItems`. This variable is then used in the final line to apply the filter to the worksheet using the `AutoFilter` method. I also excluded any number containing 3 or more consecutive zeroes from the filter but this is something that can be readily changed.

Comment: Thanks for this work around... But do you know how to use search of autofilter in VBA? as you can see in picture attached with original question

Comment: Using the macro recorder is quite often a useful way of determining which objects, methods, etc are in use but, unfortunately, not in the case of "search" in the autofilter, where the generated code includes the output of the search, but not how it is performed. Have you explored the Find method of the Range class?

Comment: Find method etc will not be efficient. Because my data is approximately a million rows. Only filter is able to do it fast.

Comment: @User1991 I have updated the answer to show a VBA workaround for the lack of search within the Autofilter method in VBA.

Comment: I am doing this in vba maco. I have decided to add a temporary column with the formula =TEXT(number,"#.####"). After my objective achieved, I deleted the temporary column within same vba macro. That's working perfect. Thanks @DMM

Comment: @User1991 if the solution has worked for you, please mark solution it as correct.